# R Markdown Parameters - can I combine vectors to use as parameters?

Tags: r, parameters, parameter-passing, r-markdown

If you type `summary(c(mtcars, cars))` into your console you will receive output. But the following R Markdown (shown below) throws the error, "*object 'test' not found*".

How do I combine vectors to use as parameters in R Markdown? Maybe this is not allowed and parameters must be either single numbers, or character strings?? I want the `test` parameter to be `c(mtcars, cars)`. Or perhaps in the future I'll have a parameter `VariableX` that I'd want to be `c("apple", "pear", "orange")`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
params:
  n: 100
  test: c(mtcars, cars)
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r test}
summary(test)
```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the [R Markdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-declare.html):

> We can also use R objects by including !r before R expressions

To access the parameter within the report using `params$test`. Putting this together:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
params:
  n: 100
  test: !r c(mtcars, cars)
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r test}
summary(params$test)
```
````

[image]